# Image unable to show when button is being pressed in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have three buttons, in which their images are hidden. Suppose that I press the button "Square", the square image will popup. When I press the "Circle" button, only the circle image will popup and the square image will be hidden and vice versa. However for my code when I click the button, it will just pop up to the top of the page without displaying the image.

```js
function showImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById('sqimg').style.visibility = "visible";
}

function showImage2() {
  var image = document.getElementById('cirimg').style.visibility = "visible";
}

function showImage3() {
  var image = document.getElementById('trimg').style.visibility = "visible";

}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <button onclick="showImage()" name="square" value="Square">Square</button> &nbsp
      <button onclick="showImage2()" name="Circle" value="Circle">Circle</button> &nbsp
      <button onclick="showImage3()" name="Triangle" value="Triangle">Triangle 
    </button>
    </form>

    <form>
      <img src="square.png" id="sqimg" style="visibility:hidden" width="100" height="100">
      <img src="circle.png" id="cirimg" style="visibility:hidden" width="100" height="100">
      <img src="triangle.png" id="trimg" style="visibility:hidden" width="100" height="100">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of `form` tag for button controls as you are handling click event for each button so no need to use <kbd>form</kbd>,

Try below code:

```js
function showImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('sqimg').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('cirimg').style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById('trimg').style.visibility="hidden";
}

function showImage2() {
    var image = document.getElementById('cirimg').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('trimg').style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById('sqimg').style.visibility="hidden";
}

function showImage3() {
    var image = document.getElementById('trimg').style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById('cirimg').style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById('sqimg').style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<div>
<button onclick="showImage()" name="square" value="Square">Square</button> &nbsp 
<button onclick="showImage2()" name="Circle" value="Circle">Circle</button> &nbsp 
<button onclick="showImage3()" name="Triangle" value="Triangle">Triangle 
</button>
</div>

<form>
<img src="square.png" id="sqimg" style="visibility:hidden" width="100" height="100">
<img src="circle.png" id="cirimg" style="visibility:hidden" width="100" height="100">
<img src="triangle.png" id="trimg" style="visibility:hidden" width="100" height="100">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Oh, and if I want to show the images in the same position of the page, do I create a class and set the position:relative to it?

Comment: Not sure! just give a try!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of three separate functions create a single function. In that single function pass the `id` of the image that you want to show as an argument.

Also use css class instead of inline style.So in the function check if if there exist an element with class `show`. If it exist then remove the class `show` from it

default button type is `submit` so add button type as `button` else it will be able to submit the form

```js
function showImage(elem) {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName('show')[0] !== undefined) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('show')[0].classList.remove('show');
  }
  var image = document.getElementById(elem).classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <button type='button' onclick="showImage('sqimg')" name="square" value="Square">Square</button> &nbsp
    <button type='button' onclick="showImage('cirimg')" name="Circle" value="Circle">Circle</button> &nbsp
    <button type='button' onclick="showImage('trimg')" name="Triangle" value="Triangle">Triangle </button>
  </form>
</div>


<form>
  <img src="square.png" id="sqimg" class='hidden' width="100" height="100">
  <img src="circle.png" id="cirimg" class='hidden' width="100" height="100">
  <img src="triangle.png" id="trimg" class='hidden' width="100" height="100">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you click one of your buttons your page is refreshing, thus making it seem as if your buttons are not working. This is happening because your buttons are within a `<form>` and so your form is submitting (hence refreshing) the page each time a button is clicked. If you remove `<form></form>` tags your page will not refresh and thus fix your issue.

See working example below:

```html
<html>
<script>
  function showImage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('sqimg').style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  function showImage2() {
    var image = document.getElementById('cirimg').style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  function showImage3() {
    var image = document.getElementById('trimg').style.visibility = "visible";

  }
</script>

<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick="showImage()" name="square" value="Square">Square</button> &nbsp
    <button onclick="showImage2()" name="Circle" value="Circle">Circle</button> &nbsp
    <button onclick="showImage3()" name="Triangle" value="Triangle">Triangle </button>
  </div>

  <img src="square.png" id="sqimg" style="visibility:hidden" width="100" height="100" alt="square">
  <img src="circle.png" id="cirimg" style="visibility:hidden" width="100" height="100" alt="circle">
  <img src="triangle.png" id="trimg" style="visibility:hidden" width="100" height="100" alt="triangle">

</body>
</html>
```